# Citation of Figures messing up the bibliography order

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing, article

I just started inserting the bibliography in my thesis and I had already written the first two references in the main text. When I inserted the 3rd reference in the title of the first figure (which is under the text with the first 2 references), the order messes up: the first reference [1] goes to the figure and then, in the text above, there are citations [2] and [3].
I used `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please post a full MWE. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Where is the physical input for the figure?  It probably occurs before the first two `\cite`s, and since the references are "unsorted", that is, in the order in which they occur in the input, the numbering "follows the rules".  In order to change the numbering, you can move the input for the figure to be after the input for the first two `\cite`s.  (May be tricky.)

Comment: Did you compile more than once? Remember LaTeX needs you to re-run in order to correct citation order.